# Appengine: Django static serve: prevent directory listing

Tags: django, .htaccess, google-app-engine, static

I have a /static/ subdirectory in my django application (hosted on appengine) which is used to  serve images, .js and .css files (with django.views.static.serve).

I would like to prevent directory listing on that subdirectory, but the .htaccess doesn't seem to work. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion in this question.

.htaccess is a feature of the Apache web server, so naturally it won't work on a site that is not being served by Apache.

django.views.static.serve is a method of serving files that is *only for development*. It must not be used in a production site - in fact, as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) states, it does not even work if `DEBUG` is False.

App Engine has its own method of serving static assets, via handler paths [configured in app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers), and this is what you should be using for an App Engine app. This method does not support directory listing anyway.

Comment: Weird. I use DEBUG = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development') in my settings.py and it seems to do the trick for the debug mode. I didn't have the static handler in my app.yaml, but django.views.static.serve was working for static files even in the deployed application. I added the handler in app.yaml, but directory listing is still available...

Comment: Okay, i put the new handler in top of my handler declarations and it works now. Anyway, django.views.static.serve is working in production environment (with DEBUG=False). I'll change that to an appengine handler. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Interesting - despite that repeated warning in the docs, there doesn't actually seem to be any code that enforces it. Weird. Still, the point remains that you should not be using it in production (even on a non-App Engine site) because it is inefficient and insecure.

Comment: Indeed. I changed it, and production seems to be a lot faster and more responsive. It's difficult to guess who's behind the static.serve code since appengine rewrote some django primitives. Anyway, you're right, it should be forbidden (like stated in the docs).